# Spring schedule cron does not work with hours

Tags: java, spring, cron, schedule, spring-scheduled

I'm trying to use Spring schedule with cron, when I use this pattern for every minute, its is ok;

```
pattern1: `0 * * * * *`
```

but when I try to give an hour for example: it should work every day at 19:00 it does not work, pattern is like below

```
pattern2: `0 * 19 * * *`
```

Note: Also I tried `0 35 19 * * *` this pattern for change and try to minutes it does not work to.

**Solved!**

It's a timezone issue.

I live in Turkey and last year our timezone changed, the interesting thing is Java still working for old timezone If I want to run a method with `@Scheduled(cron=pattern)` at 19 I have to set hour to 18 like that;

`"0 35 18 * * *"` working at 19:35:00

`"0 35 19 * * *"` is not working at 19:35:00

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  you're right, my answer couldn't have solved it if the first statement worked.

Comment: `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 19 * * *")` works for me. You should post your code that doesn't work.